# Convegence under integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of locally summable non-negative functions on $\mathbb{R}$.

Suppose that
$\int_{a}^{b}x^2\,f_n(x)\,dx \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$ for every $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ ,

1) can I conclude that
$\int_{a}^{b}f_n(x)\,dx \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$ for every $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ ?

2) can I conclude that
$f_n(x) \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$ for Lebesgue-almost every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ ?

I think the answer to 1) should be yes, I tried to prove it using a change of variable ($y=x^3$) but I didn't menage.

*Edit*:I added the hypothesis $f_n\geq0$ later.

Answer (score 1):

Neither are true. For example, $f_n (x) = \frac {1}{nx}$ on the interval $[0,1]$. This should give you a hint about what you failed to consider.

Comment: Not a counterexample to 2) though.

Comment: It was meant to only be the counter example to 1, since he was so certain the answer is yes. 2) is not true either, and you need another counter example. I do not want to add it, as that will completely give it away.

Comment: But $\frac{1}{nx}$ is not integrable on $[0,1]$..
I edit the question writing "summable" instead of "integrable" to be clearer.

Comment: @qwertyuio Yes, which is why I intentionally chose it. Now, you should be able to create a similar sequence that is actually integrable and the integral tends to infinity.

Comment: I tried with $f_n(x)=1/(n x^{1+1/n})$, but it is not a counter-example. Instead $f_n(x)=1/(n x^{1+1/n^2})$ is a counter-example, right?

Comment: There are 2 ways to 'fix' it. Both of these are common analysis 'tricks'. 1) Make $f_n=0$ for some small portion around 0 (up to you to determine exactly how small), since we're concerned that $ \int \frac {1}{nx}$ is undefined. 2) use $\frac {1}{nx^{1+ \alpha}}$. (I leave you to figure out if $\alpha > 0$ or $\alpha < 0$.)